# sql server 2008 latest date

Tags: sql-server, date, max

I'm trying to get the latest date with an output of one row. Can someone help? I have tried using inner joins, max,  and top 1 order desc. Any help is much appreciated

```
 SELECT
   ISIR_NSLDS.ISIR_NSLDS_ADDDATE
  ,ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_SUB_PR_BAL
  ,ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_COMB_TOTAL

  FROM
   ISIR_NSLDS
  WHERE
   ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_STUDENT_ID = N'0327193'
```

Comment: `select max(isir_nslds_addate)`?

Comment: what are the types of your fields?

Comment: I've tried using max(isir_nslds_addate) and all rows still show.. the dates show up as 7/5/2014 12:00:00 AM if that helps

Comment: ISIR_NSLDS.ISIR_NSLDS_ADDDATE is the dates, ,ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_SUB_PR_BAL is just a balance, ,ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_COMB_TOTAL is just a total

Comment: You said you tried "top 1 order desc". Why didn't that work?

Comment: actually, that did work. I tried doing a nested select with top 1, and for some reason didn't work. But the answer that Bcpouli put worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use group by:

```
SELECT TOP 1
   ISIR_NSLDS.ISIR_NSLDS_ADDDATE as LatestDate
  ,ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_SUB_PR_BAL
  ,ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_COMB_TOTAL
  FROM
   ISIR_NSLDS
  WHERE
   ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_STUDENT_ID = N'0327193'
  ORDER BY ISIR_NSLDS.ISIR_NSLDS_ADDDATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
SELECT MAX(ISIR_NSLDS.ISIR_NSLDS_ADDDATE)
  ,ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_SUB_PR_BAL
  ,ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_COMB_TOTAL
FROM ISIR_NSLDS
WHERE ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_STUDENT_ID = N'0327193'
GROUP BY ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_SUB_PR_BAL, ISIR_NSLDS.INSD_AG_COMB_TOTAL
```